# Database creation

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I have plan to create a database for my application which takes the name from a text field automatically.(at run textfield not null).But i have syntax error.This same code run in another java page in the same project.The following code takes the creation task.

```
 public void FacltyNameTable(){

      String fcltyName = fcltyUserNameTxt.getText();

              try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+fcltyName+"' " +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    " rollNo VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " studentName VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    "CommunicationOral INTEGER, "+
                    "Communicationwritten INTEGER, "+
                    "Leadership INTEGER, "+
                    "AnalyticalAbilities INTEGER, "+
                    "Interpersonalskills INTEGER, "+
                    "DecisionMakingSkills INTEGER, "+
                    "SelfConfidence INTEGER, "+
                    "Creativity INTEGER, "+
                    "Punctualityregularity INTEGER, "+
                    "GeneralAwareness INTEGER, "+
                    "Commitment INTEGER, "+
                    "Hardwork INTEGER, "+

                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);


             String insert1="INSERT IGNORE INTO '"+fcltyName+"'(id,rollNo,studentName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork)VALUES(1,'1','ABHIJITH V GEORGE ',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(insert1);

 }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
  try{
     if(stmt!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
  }// do nothing
  try{
     if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
  }//end finally try
 }//end try
 }
```

Following shows the error

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' (id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  rollNo VARCHAR(255),  studentName VARCH' at line 1
```

When i change 'String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"+fcltyName+"' " +........` to `String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fcltyName " +.......` its perfectly works.I think my query is Wromg.I need help please

Comment: this is a really bad idea for too many reasons to go into detail here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Connection conn=Drivermanager....etc
dont use typecasting. Also always use prepared statements. It is neat and safe.

One small error.
Eg.  id int(10) not null auto_increment must be used

size of int must be given. Assuming mysql

Answer (score 2):

Does changing this line as follows help? (removed single quotes)

```
        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+fcltyName+" " +
```

Comment: try to narrow down - try the SQL without java, if it has a problem, try one half the columns, then other half, etc. and you'll find the problem soon.

Comment: @DeepuKrishna i will delete this answer soon since of no use

Answer (score 1):

Your `fcltyUserNameTxt` is probably empty. Can you try logging:

```
String fcltyName = fcltyUserNameTxt.getText();
System.out.println(fcltyName); // ??
```